# cordova fullscreen page with the soft keyboard open

Tags: android, css, cordova, jquery-mobile, handlebars.js

Im developing an android app with cordova and am having some issues with the soft keyboard. (using this tutorial: https://ccoenraets.github.io/cordova-tutorial/creating-view-classes.html )

When I tap on an input field on my test device (nexus 5), the soft keyboard opens and the view becomes scrollable, as expected.
However, the page view shinks and some of my content is left floating on whitespace if you scroll the view up (see link below) (grey is the background image im testing with, it is shrunk by about 40% when the keyboard opens)

http://i57.tinypic.com/v6t89t.png

I spun up a tutorial version of JQuery mobile and they do not have this issue. The page loads and scrolls in full and I believe they are using some JS to hard set the height of the main element or something to that matter.
Is there a way of solving this white space issue without using an existing framework as I'd rather not want to have to hard override the JQuery mobile CSS

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the < meta > tag, I had this one myself too, fixed it by adding these meta's to the head in my index.html file

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

Comment: that has reduced the whitespace by half,however, it is still there. Another thing I have noticed is that the content on the page is not compressing when the keyboard opens in any way. So 100% of the page is still above the keyboard by default, only the containing handlebars div (not it's content) is compressing. Although i do not want the compresion, it is interesting to note that the content does not want to sit behind the keyboard by default (i can still scroll it behind the keyboard though). Any other ideas?

Comment: try experimenting with those numbers in the meta tags, see what that gives you.. if that doesn't work, i don't know.. sorry

Comment: Thanks for your help, in the end i switched to a Jquery Mobile framework and their wizardry worked fine. Css was painful tho :P

Comment: Np, i'm glad you found it :D